argparse option to create a mapping
C compilers have the -D switch to define a preprocessor constant at compilation time. It is called like -D name=value, or -D name and value defaults to 1.
Can a similar thing be done with python argparse? That is, can you create an option that meets these criteria?

The argument can be accepted multiple times
The argument takes a key-value pair
If the key is present but the value is not it should  use the default
The result is a mapping (Python dict or similar)

Desired usage:
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-D",
    #### what goes here ? ####
    default=1
)
ap.parse_args(["-D", "foo=bar", "-D", "baz"])
# ==> Namespace(D={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1})

If I just use nargs="append", I can not specify an automatic default in the add_argument call, and I additionally have to do the string processing myself on the resultant list, which is kind of hairy, and I would like to avoid that.

When you want to do something that is out of the ordinary, you have to do it yourself.  Parsing your multiple -D arguments is not a hard task.  What have you done?

I think that the fact that famous compilers use this sort of syntax is a good argument in favor of OP's requirement being quite reasonable

There is nothing in argparse directly for updating mapping types, currently. I've seen people use a normal option and then put type=json.loads as a hackaround, but it's not very likable.
I think a custom Action type meets the requirements in the question:
import argparse

class MappingAction(argparse.Action):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._default = self.default
        self.default = {}

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or {}
        key, sep, val = values.partition("=")
        if not sep:
            val = self._default
        items[key] = val
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

Using the default=1 to indicate the default value of unspecified mapping values is a bit off, so I'd encourage you to rethink that API. In the context of an add_argument call, using default=1 would suggest you want a default value of 1 in the namespace if no -D were specified. Whereas I think you'd probably prefer an empty dict as the default value in that case.
If the default doesn't need to be configurable, I'd probably recommend to remove the "indirection" used in this action and just hardcode the "1" instead of using self._default. This would simplify your action to this:
class MappingAction(argparse.Action):

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        items = getattr(namespace, self.dest) or {}
        key, sep, val = values.partition("=")
        if not sep:
            val = "1"
        items[key] = val
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, items)

Usage demo:
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-D", action=MappingAction)
args = ap.parse_args(['-Dfoo=bar', '-Dbaz', '-D', 'asd=qwe', '-D', 'hi=1'])
print(args)  # Namespace(D={'foo': 'bar', 'baz': '1', 'asd': 'qwe', 'hi': '1'})


In argparse's terminology the "1" would not be a default argument but rather a "const". The difference being: default = value when the flag is not passed whereas const = value when the flag is passed but with no argument attached to it.

@MannyC That is a good point. I will wait to hear from O.P. whether the mapping default actually needs customization at all, if the intended use-case is compiler flags it would probably just add needless complexity to support const.

sorry, I got "default value for within the mapping" vs. "default value if there is no mapping" confused. const=1, default={} probably is the best thing. I am not really rewriting exactly a compiler -D flag usage, but this helps.

Use the type argument in its generalized form which allows you to pass an arbitrary function.
You can define, for example
def parse(flag):
     if '=' in flag:
         re_match = re.match(r'(\w+)=(.*)$', flag)
         if re_match:
             return (re_match.group(1), re_match.group(2))
         else:
             raise ValueError
     else:
         return (flag, 1)

Then define the argument as
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-D', type=parse, action='append')
args = ap.parse_args(['-Dfoo=bar', '-Dbaz', '-D', 'asd=qwe', '-D', 'hi=1'])
dict(args.D)
# {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': 1, 'asd': 'qwe', 'hi': '1'}

where I used action='append' to allow the user to specify -D multiple times and store the results in a list.
You could make the regex more restrictive since the type flag catches the ValueError exception and displays a nicely formatted error message.
If, for some reason, you can't call dict after parsing and you wanna have it already a dict as soon as it is parsed, you can create a new action taking inspiration from _ActionAppend and then pass your class as the parameter action.

An int for 'baz' but a string for 'hi' seems a bit dodgy.

Yeah I guess these fine-tunings depend on the actual keywords supported. One could have some keywords produce an int and some a string, and by default a string. All this logic can go in the function parse.
